# fuction not working properly,python,pygame

Tags: python, function, loops, for-loop, pygame

it is showing no error just bringing up a blank display instead of printng start at the bottom of display

```
import pygame
import time

pygame.init()

black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)

Display = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))
pygame.display.set_caption('fitness')

font = pygame.font.SysFont(None,200)


def message_to_screen(msg,color):
    screen_text = font.render(msg,True,color)
    Display.blit(screen_text, [800/2, 600/2])

exercises =["pelvic shift","hanging","single leg hopping","puppy pose","side strech","low lunge                                                                               arcs",  "cobra strech","jogging,skipping","vertical bends","standing strechs","side bends","swimming","toe lifts","land swimming" ,"legs up alternate", "leg kicks" , "wake up stretchinggutes and hip bridges","forward spine stretch","cat camel back stetch","mermaid stretch","cycling","jump squats","cobra stretch","downward facing dog"  ,   "bird dog", "inversion table exercise", "surya namaskars" , "side planks"]             


def exerciseLoop():  
    for x in exercises:
        for number_of_exercise in range(1,29):   
            z = exercises.index(x)
            if number_of_exercise == (z+1):
                final={}
                final.update({number_of_exercise:x})
                message_to_screen("start",black)
                clock = pygame.time.Clock()
                FPS = 30
                clock.tick(FPS)
                Display.fill(white)
                pygame.display.update()
    

exerciseLoop()
```

Comment: Maybe `number_of_exercise` is not equal to `z + 1`?

Comment: You have asked the same question twice: [stuck in an infinite loop,python,pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65587837/stuck-in-an-infinite-loop-python-pygame). You shouldn't do that. Improve the original question instead of asking the same question twice.

Answer (score 0):

The white is painted above the text. You need to paint it white first, then write the text:

```
import pygame
import time

pygame.init()

black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)

Display = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))
pygame.display.set_caption('fitness')

font = pygame.font.SysFont(None,200)


def message_to_screen(msg,color):
    screen_text = font.render(msg,True,color)
    Display.blit(screen_text, [800/2, 600/2])

exercises =["pelvic shift","hanging","single leg hopping","puppy pose","side strech","low lunge                                                                               arcs",  "cobra strech","jogging,skipping","vertical bends","standing strechs","side bends","swimming","toe lifts","land swimming" ,"legs up alternate", "leg kicks" , "wake up stretchinggutes and hip bridges","forward spine stretch","cat camel back stetch","mermaid stretch","cycling","jump squats","cobra stretch","downward facing dog"  ,   "bird dog", "inversion table exercise", "surya namaskars" , "side planks"]             


def exerciseLoop():  
    for x in exercises:
        for number_of_exercise in range(1,29):   
            z = exercises.index(x)
            if number_of_exercise == (z+1):
                final={}
                final.update({number_of_exercise:x})
                Display.fill(white)
                message_to_screen("start",black)
                clock = pygame.time.Clock()
                FPS = 30
                clock.tick(FPS)
                pygame.display.update()
    

exerciseLoop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to handle the events in the application loop. See [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get) respectively [`pygame.event.pump()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump):

> For each frame of your game, you will need to make some sort of call to the event queue. This ensures your program can internally interact with the rest of the operating system.

```py
def exerciseLoop():  
     
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    FPS = 30
    run = True
    while run:
        clock.tick(FPS)
        for event in pygame.event.get(): 
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False

        for x in exercises:
            for number_of_exercise in range(1,29):  
                
                z = exercises.index(x)
                if number_of_exercise == (z+1):
                    final={}
                    final.update({number_of_exercise:x})  
                
        Display.fill(white)
        message_to_screen("start",black)
                
        pygame.display.update()
    
exerciseLoop()
```

The typical PyGame application loop has to:

- handle the events by either [`pygame.event.pump()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump) or [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get).
- update the game states and positions of objects dependent on the input events and time (respectively frames)
- clear the entire display or draw the background
- draw the entire scene (`blit` all the objects)
- update the display by either [`pygame.display.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update) or [`pygame.display.flip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip)